# My PC keeps freezing while gaming

Tags: freeze

If i'm gaming (like BioShock Infinite) for 10 minutes, my pc freezes. This means that the screen freezes, the usb ports go off and the only way to shut it down is by pressing the reset button.

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
Operating System: Windows 8 Pro 64-bit (6.2, Build 9200) (9200.win8_gdr.130108-1504)
Language: Dutch (Regional Setting: Dutch)
System Manufacturer: MSI
System Model: MS-7680
BIOS: BIOS Date: 07/20/11 10:49:24 Ver: 04.06.04
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2300 CPU @ 2.80GHz (4 CPUs), ~2.8GHz
Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 4078MB RAM
Page File: 3040MB used, 6413MB available
Windows Dir: C:\Windows
DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
Card name: ATI Radeon HD 5800 Series

-----------------
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: open control panel - select system and maintenance - administrative tools - and choose event viewer.  Does the event viewer show any errors during the times it froze. Also do you have official drivers installed for your graphics card?

Comment: There are no problems to be shown. I'm using the official catalyst for downloading the drivers. I've also scanned my pc for any virusses.

Comment: My first (and often correct) thought on "I am gaming for a few minutes and the PC crashes" is a heat problem. Could you run something to monitor the heat (e.g. GPU-z, or the catalysts overdrive screen) to confirm that this is not the case. Personally I find that this works best if you open either (or both) of those on a second display while gaming on the primary display.

Comment: cpu: 50C max and gpu: 80C. But this is normal for my pc. If i'm playing another game, it does not crash with this heat.